# How to use Bower with private Bitbucket repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket, private, bower

I'm working on a project, where I have some public bower components, and I'm writing some of my own. But, I don't want to publish/register it on bower registry. I wan't to use my PRIVATE Bitbucket repository.

So, if i type in terminal:
`bower install my_package_name`
I want to download that package from my private repo.

I get the idea, that I should specify the git repo in bower.json file, but what I'm struggling with is authentication through terminal.

Answer (score 20):

Ok, since nobody answered, I figured it out by myself. You can use with HTTPS like this:

```
{
   "dependencies" : {
       "my_package_name" : "https://username@bitbucket.org/MY_REPO_URL.git"
   }
}
```

Or with SSH:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "my_package_name": "git@bitbucket.org:username/MY_REPO_URL.git"
    }
}
```

This works like a charm.

Comment: Hi I have exactly the same issue, but you have not yet fully answered how you got past the authentication problems because it is a private repository.

Comment: Me and my team have an access on that private repository. 
When you run the `bower install` command from Terminal, you'll get a prompt to set your username/password. If you have an access to the repo, installation will continue, if not, you'll get an error, saying that you don't have an access.

Comment: @LadoLomidze It does not actually answer the problem, yes you can do bower install manually. but what if you deployment build. you deployment build script must able to pull it automatically.

Comment: Not sure about that, because we never used tools like that before. But, I believe, theoretically, it is possible to setup some kind of connection between Bitbucket and the Deployment service, which will "have access" to these repositories and the problem will be solved. Can you tell me, what service to you use to build automatically?

Comment: @LadoLomidze You can set it up with ssh keys instead, thats how I did it with jenkins and projects with private repos as dependencies

Comment: @CodeMonkey See the answer and my comment below.

Comment: @LadoLomidze how did you manage to register the private bit repo on bower? Can you help me in this?

Comment: @Ajay You don't need to "register" on bower. It will read the "dependencies" object from the bower.json file and will try to download it (if the repo name is not registered on bower).

Comment: @LadoLomidze. we downloaded it by adding it as a dependency in bower.json. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 11):

Use SSH-like clone URL:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "my_package_name": "git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git"
    }
}
```

Your system should have authorized SSH key.

It works for me! Good luck!

Comment: This QA is littler older and I haven't updated my answer since then. I'm using SSH already, so if anyone else will see this comment, I would recommend to use the SSH version, rather then HTTPS.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect with HTTPS or SSH. You can find the connection string under the overview page of your Bitbucket repository.
To use ssh you need to setup ssh.

You can use HTTPS:

```
bower install https://YOUR_USER_NAME@bitbucket.org/YOUR_USER_NAME/PROJECT_NAME.git --save
```

or use SSH:

```
bower install git@bitbucket.org:YOUR_USER_NAME/PROJECT_NAME.git --save
```

Or add it in your bower.json file as a dependency and run :

```
bower install
```

HTTPS - bower.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "PROJECT_NAME": "https://YOUR_USER_NAME@bitbucket.org/YOUR_USER_NAME/PROJECT_NAME.git"
}
```

SSH - bower.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
  "PROJECT_NAME": "git@bitbucket.org:YOUR_USER_NAME/PROJECT_NAME.git"
}
```

To setup ssh for Bitbucket follow the instruction in their documentation:
[Set up SSH for Git](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might also setup an SSH connection between your account and the repo. That way you won't have to supply username/password.

Atlassian have a long nice step-by-step wizard on how to to just that. It's too long to rewrite here so I'll leave a link :)

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked:

```
"repo_name": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/repo_name.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

## With clean `https://bitbucket` or `https//github` urls

You need `~/.netrc` file. It is easy.

Github example:

```
 echo machine github.com login ${YOUR_USERNAME} password ${YOUR_TOKEN_OR_PASSWORD} >> ~/.netrc
```